# CountDownTimer inside Popup

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, countdowntimer

Ohke, so I've updated to this:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder popup_timer = new AlertDialog.Builder(ScoreNewGame.this);
popup_timer.setTitle("Timer:\t90 sec between games");
    CountDownTimer gameTimer = new CountDownTimer(9000, 1000) 
    {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long time_remaining) 
        {
            popup_timer.setMessage("Time remaining:\t" + time_remaining);
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() 
        {
        }
    };
    gameTimer.start();
    popup_timer.show();
```

But now I get the following error-

```
Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
```

I searched around a bit but can't find any solution. Also, 0x010802c9 doesn't correspond to anything in R.java.
The app doesn't crash though, the popup just doesn't display the countdowntimer like I want

Comment: Can you post a crash log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a dialog fragment instead. At that point you can handle the countdown timer in the fragment any which way you want.

Here's an example of a dialog fragment:

```
public class CountDownDialog extends DialogFragment {

private TextView mCountdownView;

public CountDownDialog(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_countdowntimer_dialog, container);
    mCountdownView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.countdownTimer);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    CountDownTimer gameTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {
            mCountdownView.setText(""+((int)Math.round(l/1000.0)-1));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            dismiss();
        }
    };
    gameTimer.start();
}
}
```

and here's how you would call it

```
    CountDownDialog countDownDialog = new CountDownDialog();
    countDownDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "fragment_countdownTimer");
```

I used a pretty simple layout for the fragment to to test it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Countdown:"
        android:id="@+id/countdownTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/countdownTimer"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that and I'm pretty new in Android. I updated my code though, please have a look. Thanx

Comment: Hi, sorry have been away for a while. Works like a charm, thank you so much!

Comment: I Dothank you my friend. All I need to know was, calling inner class should be called inside onActivityCreated method
Class
http://hastebin.com/ohepitazux.avrasm
xml. http://hastebin.com/izidoxuneq.xml